# How i can solve rails 5 secret key error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, authentication

I have secret key error in my rails 5 app.

It says `KeyError: key not found: :secret_key_base`.
I think its not generating token for sign in user.

It started to give me error after cloning project from github.But before that when it wasn't cloned it worked normally.

Comment: You almost certainly had a secrets.yml file locally, these aren't stored on Github for security reasons

Comment: Do you have access to your local version still? In your recycling bin? If so copy across the file: config/secrets.yml over to your github directory

Comment: @Mark what about the aforementioned "security reasons"?

Comment: @Mark No unfortunately i have no access to that file.But one more thing i haven’t seen any secret.yml on rails files.

Comment: Did you solved this issue and if you solved how did you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`secrets.yml` files are not sent to version control and so you must create your own file locally and then run `rails secret`. Copy the newly generated value into your 
**config/secrets.yml** like so:

`development:
  secret_key_base: insert-copied-key-here`

Comment: I did that but it gives another error.It says rails aborted mapping values are not allowed in this context.

Comment: Are you using tabs or spaces? yaml files only allow for space indentations. I had that error before and I had to change all indentation to spaces.

Comment: I have space after developement: and after secret_key_base:

Comment: Could you share you yaml snippet?

Comment: development: secret_key_base: secret_key

Comment: okay remember, the `secret_key_base:` must be on a new line though. a single space

Comment: Ok it worked but the main problem stays and it wants a secret key.

Comment: I am using Knock

Comment: This is frustrating. But which version of rails are you using because there has been some compatibility issue with rails 5.2 and the credentials

Comment: I think the problem comes from this line of code in knock.rb file `config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { Rails.application.credentials.fetch(:secret_key_base) }`

Comment: I am using rails 5.2.2

Comment: I changed config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { Rails.application.credentials.fetch(:secret_key_base) } to config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { Rails.application.credentials.read }